# Unity javascript array problems

Tags: arrays, unity-game-engine, boo

I have next code

```
var D3s = new Array(9);
var D3n: float[];
result = Mine(result);
function Mine(block) {
    D3n = new float[5];
    var init = false;
    if (block.startsWith("##new#")) {
        block = block.replace("##new#", "");
        init = true;
        D3n[3] = 16;
    }
    var s1 = block.split("&");
    s1.forEach(foreachBlocks);
    if (init) {
        //set default values
        D3n[1] = 0;
        D3s[6] = "ff";
        D3n[2] = 0;
    }
    return TurnM79();
}
```

and error: CompilationErrorsException: script(9,9): BCE0005: Boo.Lang.Compiler.CompilerError: Unknown identifier: 'D3n'.

what wrong?

Comment: ar D3n: float[] = new float[5];

Comment: but it is not help